# How to design PE42441 in Altium

Tags: altium, footprint

I've seen the PE42441 datasheet and I want to design the footprint in Altium. Regarding the datasheet, it has a 5*5(32pin) LGA pinout which is not exactly the LGA as I expected. I want to know how you design this chip footprint in Altium without manually designing each Pin.

Comment: What Altium support or forum sites have you been on to that didn't give you this answer? [Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have stated, designing a footprint is really just copying the information given to you in the datasheet.

In your .PCBLIB you can select

1. 'New Blank Footprint' (I do this 95% of the time)
2. 'Footprint Wizard' (3%)
3. Search for a premade footprint, such as here
   https://www.snapeda.com/parts/PE42441C-Z/pSemi/view-part/?ref=search&t=PE42441%20

Sometimes you can find a Schematic component, the PCB footprint, and even a realistic 3D model.  I use this for the other 2%.

If you choose option 3, be very careful to look at every layer, including the solder mask and solder paste layers, and measure! The most useful command IMO is **Reports** > **Measure Primitives**

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know how you design this chip footprint in Altium without
> manually designing each Pin.

I don't really understand the problem. Designing a footprint like that should take about 10 minutes. All the dimensions are provided in the datasheet.

The other manual work that you may need to do includes:

1. Drawing silkscreen.
2. Drawing assembly outline on the mechanical layer.
3. Finding or designing a 3D model.